# Вопрос по теме алгоритм Дейкстры и графы

Tags: алгоритм

Будет ли давать алгоритм Дейкстры правильный ответ в графе, в котором ребро с отрицательным весом? Если нет то можете объяснить почему

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос ваши попытки решить задачу. Без этого учебный вопрос закроют.

Comment: вопрос не понятен... алгоритм дейкстры существует один (подразумевая, что речь о поиске кратчайшего пути в графах) и на графах с отричательными весами рёбер он не работает...

Comment: В Вике пишут  -- [Для графа с отрицательными весами применяется более общий алгоритм — Алгоритм Дейкстры с потенциалами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B#cite_note-2)

Comment: Наверное имеет смысл начать с чтения статьи [Задача о кратчайшем пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) в той же вике

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, для графов с отрицательными весами алгоритм Дейкстры в общем случае не работает, что называется *by design*, например можно рассмотреть следующий граф:

```
    /-\    2    /-\     1    /-\
    |S| ------> |A| -------> |B|
    \-/         \-/          \-/
      \         ^
       \       /
     4  \     / -3
         \   /
          v /   
          /-\ 
          |C| 
          \-/
```

Стартовая вершина `S`. На первом шаге алгоритм присвоит длину минимального пути до вершин `A` и `С` и отметит вершину `S`, как посещённую:

```
    X 0           2            ∞
    /-\    2    /-\     1    /-\
    |S| ------> |A| -------> |B|
    \-/         \-/          \-/
      \         ^
       \       /
     4  \     / -3
         \   /
          v /   
          /-\ 
          |C| 
          \-/ 
             4
```

Далее он будет рассматривать вершину `A` (т.к. длина пути до неё минимальна) присвоит длину пути до вершины `B` и отметит `A`, как посещённую:

```
    X 0         X 2            3
    /-\    2    /-\     1    /-\
    |S| ------> |A| -------> |B|
    \-/         \-/          \-/
      \         ^
       \       /
     4  \     / -3
         \   /
          v /   
          /-\ 
          |C| 
          \-/ 
             4
```

Дальше он будет рассматривать вершину `B` но т.к. достежимых вершин из неё нет, то просто отметит её как посещённую, и вершину `С`, но т.к. все вершины достижимые из неё посещены, то он также просто отметит её как посещённую:

```
    X 0         X 2          X 3
    /-\    2    /-\     1    /-\
    |S| ------> |A| -------> |B|
    \-/         \-/          \-/
      \         ^
       \       /
     4  \     / -3
         \   /
          v /   
          /-\ 
          |C| 
          \-/ 
          X 4
```

Это и будет результатом работы алгоритма, но т.к. очевидно, что цена пути до вершины `A` по пути `S`→`C`→`A` составляет всего `1`, а не `2` то результат работы алгоритма, очевидно, не верен.

---

Для поиска кратчайшего пути на графах с отрицательными весами рёбер есть другие алгоритмы, например [Беллмана — Форда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Отличное описание, очень кратко и понятно